# Tem como pegar o index da lista dentro do for-each em java?

Tags: java

Quando criamos o `for` tradicional fazemos desta forma:

```
for(int i = 0; i<strs.lenght; i++){
     Log.wtf(TAG, "Jon Snow is "+strs[i]);
}
```

Agora tenho o seguinte `for`*each*:

```
for(String str: strs){
    Log.wtf(TAG, "Jon Snow is "+str);
}
```

Em alguns casos, necessitamos do `index`. Quanto ao `for` tradicional, tudo bem, já é declarado nele mesmo. E se for no `for`*each*? Tem como pegar o *index* da lista dentro do `for`*each* em Java? Se eu declarar um `int i` fora dele, e incrementar dentro é uma prática legal caso não seja possível recuperar o *index*, ou é melhor criar um `for` tradicional?

Comment: Você poderia fazer isso utilizando o método indexOf se utilizar um List, mas com um array acho que não tem como

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza isso tem problemas de performance (`o(n)` para listas desordenadas), além de problemas com possíveis repetições (se eu tiver 5 vezes o mesmo elemento, creio que `indexOf` retorne a primeira posição válida).

Answer (score -1):

Já pesquisei bastante sobre isso e muitos dizem que não tem como.
Também já pesquisei no javadoc e não achei nada.
Acho que a solução é ou usar o for normal ou usar um contador dentro do próprio foreach.

```
int i = 0; 
for(String str : strs){
    i++;
}
```